# Drag and drop to specific area of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

```
<div id="main_div">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery `draggable` and `dropabble` for drag and drop.

I want when element drop on `main_div`, it drops to `div4` instead of `main_div`.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#main_div" ).droppable();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: @Eddie yes i update my question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#main_div").droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $item = $(ui.helper);
    $($(this).find('#div4')).append($item);
  }
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/1fh6uj57/10/)